# How are they writing this? Is this a symbol or are they reducing the height of uppercase letters to lowercase?

Tags: symbols

In a lot of papers, I find 'II' as seen below. Its an uppercase i but its height is truncated around the height of lowercase letters. How is this being done? Are they reducing the text size while writing 'II' or is there a symbol for this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Normally, this is obtained as `\textsc{II}` if the font has a bold small caps version.

Comment: @Bernard Hi, I think that it is better `\textbf{He \textsc{ii}}` instead of `\textsc{II}`. My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano: not knowing the context, I supposed the code is already inserted in a  `\textbf` or `\bfseries`. But maybe  you're right. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like a little example, I add a MWE using:

- `newtxtext` package the clone of Times New Roman;
- and the option `\scriptsize{II}` into a bold enviroment `\textbf{...}`.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
   
\begin{document}
\textbf{He \scriptsize{II}}
\end{document}
```

This is the screenshot with the green straight lines, done with Paint of OS Windows, where you can see the alignment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved!